# MongoDB query using find

Tags: mongodb

I am in the process of learning MongoDB and here is the scenario.

I am trying to find user with id. I wrote the code as

**Stmt 1**

```
query = {};
query["_id"] = { $ne: ObjectId(data._id) }
```

It returns me the user with ID. (I have only one test user as of now. So i am not so clear it returns all the user  or only user matching the id). But the logic i made is id should not be equal to.

I changed the code like

**Stmt 2**

```
 query = {};
 query = { "_id": { $ne: ObjectId(data._id) } };
```

Now this is giving me empty array as there are no users matching the id.

What difference does it make in the query to mongodb and why the query failed.

Comment: There should be no difference here. The only difference might be the value of `data._id`.

Comment: I would recommend not testing with "production" data. You say you have only 1 user. Why not make a test collection with a few more objects?

Comment: Which driver/framework/client and which exact code do you use to actually execute the query?